# How to write a for loop that splits data based on matching column value in R

Tags: r, dataframe, split, sum, subset

I am struggling with the logical reasoning of writing a for loop. Consider the following two dataframes:

```
>> df1
     A    B      C             hit_time  E
0  bar  one  small  2019-12-11 19:16:51  1 
1  bar  one  large  2019-12-09 20:21:43  2 
2  foo  two  large  2019-12-11 15:11:24  1 
3  bar  two  small  2019-12-05 16:41:21  2 
4  bar  two  small  2019-12-06 17:31:20  3 
5  bar  one  large  2019-12-03 19:13:06  2 
6  bar  one  small  2019-12-04 18:25:04  1 
7  bar  two  small  2019-12-02 21:45:38  1 
8  bar  two  large  2019-12-08 20:32:44  1 

>> df2
     X    Y      Z            Phase_One            Phase_Two          Phase_Three
0  foo  one  small  2019-12-01 06:18:00  2019-12-01 06:38:00  2019-12-01 06:48:00
1  bar  one  small  2019-12-01 06:33:00  2019-12-01 06:53:00  2019-12-01 07:03:00  
2  foo  two  large  2019-12-11 15:01:24  2019-12-11 15:21:24  2019-12-11 15:31:24
3  bar  two  small  2019-12-05 16:31:21  2019-12-05 16:51:21  2019-12-05 17:01:21  
4  bar  two  small  2019-12-06 17:21:20  2019-12-06 17:41:20  2019-12-06 17:51:20 
5  bar  one  large  2019-12-03 19:03:06  2019-12-03 19:23:06  2019-12-03 19:33:06
6  bar  one  large  2019-12-04 18:15:04  2019-12-04 18:35:04  2019-12-04 18:45:04 
7  bar  two  large  2019-12-02 21:35:38  2019-12-02 21:55:38  2019-12-02 22:05:38 
8  bar  two  large  2019-12-08 20:22:44  2019-12-08 20:42:44  2019-12-08 20:52:44
```

Now I am trying to accomplish the following in the for loop:

1. Split the df1 on column C values
2. Split the df2 on the same values in column Z
3. Calculate the following:

```
df3 <- df2[, Phase_One_   := df1[df2,on=.(hit_time >= Phase_One,  hit_time <= Start_Time), sum(E),by=.EACHI]$V1]
df3 <- df2[, Phase_Two_   := df1[df2,on=.(hit_time >= Start_Time, hit_time <= Phase_Two),  sum(E),by=.EACHI]$V1]
df3 <- df2[, Phase_Three_ := df1[df2,on=.(hit_time >= Phase_Two,  hit_time <= Phase_Three),sum(E),by=.EACHI]$V1]
```

4. rbind all the data so that the sum has happened based on the matching values in `df1$C` and `df2$Z` respectively.

Now I do understand that for loops are slow, so any suggestions are welcome to be able to sum the E column into a new data frame in the new columns based on the last three columns containing the different time frames in df2.
Thanks in advance.

Comment: I am not sure why you need to split two dfs. You can add `C=Z` to your `on` part. Also you miss `start_time` column in your `df2`.

Comment: When adding that to the on part, it did not seem to yield the desired result. For the `Start_Time`, imagine it there, the same way as the other time frames.

Answer (score 0):

I wrote a function that does just that for another project. (splitting the dataframes, you can calculate what you want after that reference the correct table in the output list)

```
multifilter <- function(data,filterorder){  
  #error if filter(s) do not exsist
  if(any(is.na(match(filterorder,names(data))))==T){stop("Atleast one filter does not exsist")}
  newdata <- list(data)
  for(i in rev(filterorder)){
    newdata <- unlist(lapply(sort(unique(data[,i])), function(x) lapply(newdata, function(y) y[y[,i]==x,])),recursive=F)
  }
  return(newdata[sapply(newdata,nrow)>=1])
}
```

you can call it like this `multifilter(df1,"C")`. The function itself is more complex than your task because it can actually accept more than one filter, for example `multifilter(df2,"c("Y","Z"))`. If you'd ever like to stitch back together an output form the multi filter you can use `do.call(rbind, multi_filter_data)`